# Parsing XML data with XDocument / XElement

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

While trying to parse through an RSS feed for a blog, I am running into a problem. While every element goes into my class fine, the one containing the actual content is always empty.

`<content:encoded>THIS IS FULL OF HTML
</content:encoded>`

Thats the XML line that it doesn't seem to parse. Its also the only one with a colon, and the only one that contains HTML data. The others look like this.

```
<title>
An amazing Title
</title>
<link>
More Junk
</link>
<comments>
Comments and things
</comments>
```

My Code is below, which gets every other element fine. Any ideas?

```
allPosts = (from x in feed.Descendants("item")
                         select new blogPost
                         {
                             Creator = (string)x.Element("creator"),
                             Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                             Published = DateTime.Parse((string)x.Element("pubDate")),
                             Content = (string)x.Element("content"),
                             Description = (string)x.Element("description"),
                             Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                         }).ToList<blogPost>();
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you point us at the RSS feed? Also, you may want to run it through an RSS validator like: http://www.rssboard.org/rss-validator/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for content and not for encoded. Content is the [XML Namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/) associated with the encoded element. What you need is to define a proper XNamespace for it and adding it to your query:

```
XNamespace contentNS = "<whatever the namespace is>";

allPosts = (from x in feed.Descendants("item")
                         select new blogPost
                         {
                             Creator = (string)x.Element("creator"),
                             Title = (string)x.Element("title"),
                             Published = DateTime.Parse((string)x.Element("pubDate")),

                             // Looking for content:encoded
                             Content = (string)x.Element(contentNS + "encoded"),

                             Description = (string)x.Element("description"),
                             Link = (string)x.Element("link"),
                         }).ToList<blogPost>();
```

The value of contentNS depends on what is present in your original XML, try to look for a xmlns:content definition in the root element.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem I was having was that there was no xmlns:content definition anywhere in the file. I eventually found it by looking through some RSS docs online. Why it isn't included in the file I'm not sure.